# Ordering by count of items associated table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I have model `Gif`, which has has_many `gif_statistics`. `GifStatistic` model has field `status` with possible options: `like` or `dislike`.
I have query like
`Gif.joins(:gif_statistics).where(...)`. And i want to order this query depending on count of either `liked`gif_statistics`or`disliked`, for ex.

**pseudocode**

`Gif.joins(:gif_statistics).where(...).order("gifs.gifs_statistics.where(state: "liked").count)")`

I tried to apply `sort` method, but that didn't work. What else could i try to achieve this? Also i only have order by count after `where` clause

Comment: order this query depending on count of either liked gif_statisticsordisliked . didn't get you.. Show your full query..

Answer (score 2):

Please let me try an answer. I would certainly do this in straight SQL. You can always do your agregation in Ruby, with arrays and maps but that'll yield poor performance. Here is your SQL query (please correct any error as I don't have your schema, hence I can't test it).

```
select g.id, s.status, count(s.status) cnt
from gifs g
inner join gif_statistics s
  on g.id = s.gif_id
group by g.id, s.status
order by cnt
```

Now see this document for running the SQL in ruby:

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#finding-by-sql

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Gif.joins(:gif_statistics).where(...).order('gif_statistics.status DESC')
```

Such query will return Gifs ordered by gif_statistics.status. Use DESC or ASC for alphabetical order of like/dislike.